# What are the physical anti-theft protection for MacBook Pro (2015 Retina)

Tags: macbook-pro, security

Since the slot for Kensington cables has been removed from the MacBook Pro Retina: what are the possibility to physically protect a MacBook Pro (2015 and 15 inch model) against thieves?

The goal is to prevent the computer to be stolen in a library, coffee, conference room, hotel lobby when I am next to the computer, but not currently working on it (e.g. discussion with somebody else, looking for something in my bag...) and not to leave it alone in the open.

Answer (score 1):

**You get a case with a lock.**

The [Ledge Case MacBook Pro Touch Bar Lock](http://radnex.us/ledge--case-lock) is a nice one that a relative showed me the other day, because he, like you tend to have their MacBook Pro out in the open in coffee shops and will leave it unattended.

[image]

Disclaimer:  I have never used nor owned one of these because I simply won't leave any computer/device unattended.  I had my personal laptop stolen from work (at the University Library) when I put down my laptop bag to punch in (still used cards back then).  In the time it took for me to walk the 20 feet (3m) from my desk to the time clock, it was gone.  Since then, my device is either on me, or physically locked away.

Answer (score 0):

There are some similar solutions to the Kensington method.

You can buy third party physical security solutions which work in the same way as them such as [this one](http://www.elara.ie/productdetail.aspx?mancode=MBPR15BRWEDGE&manufacturer=COMPULOCKS&gclid=CjwKCAiAtorUBRBnEiwAfcp_Y14p78j6n1qi41J2bubLM1E4jm9V0Y_zRiipgXyo4mRZVTPFOl10fRoCbYAQAvD_BwE) for example.

Many companies offer these kinds of solutions.